# Flutter A Render Flex overflowed by 27 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner  in the flutter and  I used  `body: SingleChildScrollView`  but not scrolled, Emulator - **Pixel 2 API 25 / 1080x1920:420dpi**
any solution for this

Thanks

here the issue

> A Render Flex overflowed by 27 pixels on the bottom

error in image
[image]

**here the code**

```
import 'package:crmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;*/

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            _signUp(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signUp() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF2A3476),
                Color(0xFF2A3476),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 36.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Ceate Account",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 34.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*  SizedBox(
                     height: 10.0,
                   ),*/
                      /*      Text(
                     "Enter to a beautifiul world",
                     style:  TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                       fontSize: 20.0,
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,

                     ),
                   )*/
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Hello, sign up to",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "circular",
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "continue",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "circular",
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Enter your first name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                              hintText: "Your First Name",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Enter your first name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                              hintText: "Your First Name",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Enter your first name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                              hintText: "Your First Name",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Enter your first name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                              hintText: "Your First Name",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                      spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    colors: [
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                    ])),
                            child: Text(
                              'Next',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                flex: 10,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If my ans worked, mark it as answer to help other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are using SingleChildScrollView with the container. Use it with the nearest Column widget.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
             // Expanded( // remove this widget
             // flex: 2,

//           ...

             //   Expanded( // remove this too
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
```

- Also, remove `Scaffold` in `_signUp` method. More than one scaffold is not required on a page.
- Remove all `Expanded` widgets inside SingleChildScroll View, or it will cause an error in the rendering library as it has infinite space.
- A working code (font size varies because I had to change it to trigger error in my emulator)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SignUpScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;*/

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            _signUp(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signUp() {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 36.0, horizontal: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Create Account",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*  SizedBox(
                   height: 10.0,
                 ),*/
                  /*      Text(
                   "Enter to a beautiful world",
                   style:  TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 20.0,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,

                   ),
                 )*/
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Hello, sign up to",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "circular",
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "continue",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "circular",
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Enter your first name',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                          hintText: "Your First Name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Enter your first name',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                          hintText: "Your First Name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Enter your first name',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                          hintText: "Your First Name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Enter your first name',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFe7edeb),
                          hintText: "Your First Name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  spreadRadius: 2)
                            ],
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                colors: [
                                  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                  Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                ])),
                        child: Text(
                          'Next',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to added but its cant do that getting error

Comment: remove scaffold before SingleChildScrollView. More than one scaffold per page is not needed

Comment: Hi I removed  but showing error, can you please put the answer using  your method

Comment: I edited the answer and checked it on my own system. It works now

Comment: Now its worked for me, Thanks for your valuable time and answer